# Can anyone explain the output that I am getting while compiling this program?

Tags: java

I executed the below mentioned code, when I got a strange output. Can anyone please explain why I am getting this output ?

*Code:*

```
public class Bar {

    static void foo( int... x ) {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
    static void foo2( float... x ) {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
            Bar.foo(3,3,3,0);
            Bar.foo2(3,3,3,1);
            Bar.foo(0);
    }
}
```

*Output*

```
[I@7a67f797
[F@3fb01949
[I@424c2849
```

Why are we getting the `"[I@"`/`"[F@"` prefixes and the 8 alphanumeric characters to follow, are they memory address ?

Comment: Are you sure you are talking about "compiling"  the program and not about "running"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Java arrays have a `toString()` method that simply display the type of the array (`[I`), followed by an `@`, followed by the hash code of the array (`7a67f797`). This value is almost meaningless. And `toString()` is the method called on every object passed to `System.out.println()`.

If you want to see the contents of the array, then use `java.util.Arrays.toString(array)`.

Comment: Can you kindly tell me how to use this method in the above mentioned code ?

Comment: `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x));`

Answer (score 3):

`float...` is syntactic sugar for `float[]`, so

```
System.out.println(x);
```

...is trying to output an array. So you're getting the [default `toString` behavior of objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29), rather than the values in the array.

To output the array, either loop through it, or use something like [`Arrays.toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28float%5B%5D%29):

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x));
```

---

> ...and the 8 alphanumeric characters to follow, are they memory address ?

No, they're just the object's hash code (this is covered in [the first link above](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29)).

Answer (score 1):

Use this to see values in array.

```
System.out.println(x[0]);
System.out.println(x[1]);
....
System.out.println(x[3]);
```

Answer (score 1):

1) foo( int... x ) is called varargs (variable arguments). Compiler replaces Bar.foo(3,3,3,0) with actual Bar.foo(new int[] {3, 3, 3, 0})

2) You are printing float and int arrays. They inherit toString from Object:

```
 public String toString() {
        return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
   }
```

`[I` and `[F` are class names for int[] and float[], try this

```
System.out.println(float[].class.getName());
```

output

```
[F
```